# Where is jaybird for ARM binary/source?

Tags: arm, firebird, jaybird

Here is Jaybird download page : http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/jdbc-driver/

it include a shared library ( libjaybird22.so ).

here is checked result with "file" command in Linux (ARM machine)
/usr/share/java/JayBird-2.2.10/libjaybird22.so: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=0x487ab75a908c792dd288322b0a0e088870ca8cb8, not stripped

This is ELF 32-bit binary. Then, To use Jaybird in ARM is not possible.
I tried. but it make error message.

Where is libjaybird22 source code ? or binary ?
I want to compile it on my ARM.

Comment: When a project site has a "Development" section, that's usually where I'd expect to find links to source code, [and sure enough](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/devel-jdbc-driver/)...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `libjaybird22.so` to use Jaybird! It is only necessary when you need to use the native or local protocols (using `libfbclient.so`), or embedded protocol (using `libfbembed.so`). For normal Jaybird connections to a Firebird server (the 'pure java' implementation), you don't need it.

So if you just want to connect to Firebird, you are good to go without `libjaybird22.so`.

If you do need it (and IMO the only real reason would be if you want to run Firebird embedded inside your Java process), the sources of Jaybird 2.2.10 are in the [Jaybird 2.2.10 release tag](https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/jaybird/releases/tag/v2.2.10) (or otherwise in [Branch_2_2](https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/jaybird/tree/Branch_2_2) of the [Jaybird repository](https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/jaybird)). For compiling you need to have Java installed + a C++ compiler (eg gcc), and use `./build.sh compile-native`; however keep in mind that it has never been tested on ARM, so it is entirely possible that you run into problems.

Full disclosure: I am one of the Jaybird developers.

If you need to make any changes to get it compiling, I'm happy to receive pull requests.